# IIS website is missing ASP.NET features

Tags: iis, .net-framework, asp.net

I have a site, which I have hooked up to IIS (10). Currently, I can't access my site, because I get a internal server error when I access it, and then it has this info:

> This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file  for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs  may contain more information about what caused this error

But I was talking to someone who had done the same job earlier, who noticed that there was no ASP.NET section under the site in IIS:

> [image: Screenshot.]

Just below "Management" there should be a section for ASP.NET  features.

This would make sense, as I think I maybe installed IIS before getting .NET framework.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811560/missing-asp-net-features-on-iis-10-0) StackOverflow question, answering the same thing, which gave an answer looking like this:

```
"Add roles and features" -> 
   "Server Roles" -> 
      "Web Server (iis)" ->
         "Web Server" ->
            "Application Development" -> 
               "ASP.NET 4.6" (I also needed 3.5 for legacy reasons)
```

But when I install server manager, and try clicking "add roles and features", I get a message saying:

> Either there are no servers in the Server Manager server pool, or there are no servers that support remote installation or removal of roles and features. To add supported servers, use the Add Servers command on the Manage menu of the Server Manager console.

I tried adding my service, but could'nt find any useful guides on how to add my IIS server. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: “I found this StackOverflow question, answering the same thing…” What StackOverflow question? Please provide a URL so we can all see the answer you saw.

Comment: Server Manager is software for Windows Server and there is no need to install it - it's already there. I think your have Windows 10, so that this StackOverflow question and Server Manager are irrelevant to you.

Comment: If you have Windows 10, run the command `optionalfeatures` from a command prompt (or using [win]+R). From there you can install the .NET framework itself (if not installed yet), and the IIS ASP.NET features

Comment: "This would make sense, as I think I maybe installed IIS before getting .NET framework." - Impossible if you are running any supported version of WIndows or Windows Server.

Comment: A few things. The linked question is added now. Server manager was not installed by default, I installed it myself, I don't understand how they would be irrelevant. Also, my issue is not that I don't have .net framework installed